# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged not firing (AutoPostBack="true")

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownList on my webpage inside update panel. When I select a different value from the drop-down list, nothing happens which  means that the "SelectedIndexChanged" event is not firing.

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <table class="table table-mv-vouchers" style="margin:0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <caption class="mv-clearfix">                            
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShort" Width="150"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  EnableViewState="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlShort_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Estimate" Value="EstimateValue"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Merchant" Value="MerchantName" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Type" Value="MerchantCategory"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Validity" Value="Validity"></asp:ListItem>                        
                        </asp:DropDownList>                                                          
                        </caption>
                        </table>
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server Side Code:

```
protected void ddlShort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ByShort = ddlShort.SelectedValue;
    if (ByShort != null)
    {
        DataSet dsAllMerchant = Main.Instance.serClient.GetMerchantList(null,true, ByShort, null,currentBaID,true);
        DataTable newdata = this.GenerateData(dsAllMerchant.Tables[0]);
        lvGiftVoucher.DataSource = newdata;
        lvGiftVoucher.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the post back happen at all when you change the value of the drop down?

Comment: Usually this happens if the dropdown is bound in postback as well

Comment: Check list Id in post back and make sure exactly same as initial one (maybe it's parent change the id in postback)

Comment: you need to put dropdown controls outside of update panel

Comment: when r u populating the dropdownlist value.?? is it at pageload? do a check `if(!IsPostBack)` during dropdownlist population time..

Comment: Andrei, PostBack don't happen
Sachu, Dropdown populated on aspx page. Please see aspx code

Comment: @Liton, then it got to be the update panel who causes the problem. Can you share its markup?

Comment: Remove UpdatePanel and check if it fires the event - Just to make sure its got something to do with UpdatePanel only.

Comment: is your webpage created with master page?

Comment: yes , i have used master page

Comment: so check that you include form tag in master page not in webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was `<caption class="mv-clearfix"> </caption>` tag, I think this tag is not recognize. After deleting this tag dropdownlist is firing. Thanks all for your answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a trigger to your UpdatePanel, like that:

```
<asp:updatepanel ...>
   <triggers>
       <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="DrpEmployeeType" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </triggers>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Comment: Its not working 
 <Triggers>
                 <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="ddlShort" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>

Answer (score 0):

Change UpdatePanel update mode to always

```
UpdateMode="Always"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have:

- a `ScriptManager` on your page
- an `UpdatePanel` which wraps the `lvGiftVoucher` markup
- provided a unique Id to you update-panel
- an `AsyncPostbackTrigger` for dropdown `SelectedIndexChanged` event
- set `UpdateMode` to `Conditional`
- `AutoPostback = "True"` for the dropdwonlist (you already did it)

**Dropdown markup (as is, just remove the updatepanel wrap)**

```
<table class="table table-mv-vouchers" style="margin:0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<caption class="mv-clearfix">                            
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShort" Width="150"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  EnableViewState="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlShort_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="By Estimate" Value="EstimateValue"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="By Merchant" Value="MerchantName" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="By Type" Value="MerchantCategory"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="By Validity" Value="Validity"></asp:ListItem>                        
</asp:DropDownList>                                                          
</caption>
</table>
```

**UpdatePanel mark-up**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTrigger="False">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlId="ddlShort" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- lvGiftVoucher markup here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Also, remove the UpdatePanel which is wrapping the dropdownlist. Inside an UpdatePanel markup you should only keep the things which will be updated.

Comment: @mshsayem Do we set both `AutoPostBack=True` and `AsyncPostbackTrigger` for Dropdown ?

Comment: I am using only one updatePanel for whole control/page

Comment: Dont do that. Use the UpdatePanel To wrap only the `lvGiftVoucher ` markup (as shown above); and set UpdateMode to Conditional with a trigger which has the event selectedIndexChange of the dropdown (outside of the updatepanel).

Comment: AutoPostback="True" is the dropdownlist property. AsyncPostbackTrigger is an UpdatePanel element. You need both.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  Sachu.....Server Side Coding, on "PageLoad Event" ....(!IsPostback) Event should happen inside  & call "Drop downList"

Answer (score 0):

is your webpage created with master page? If so then check that your form tag is in which page master page/webpage. If it is in master page then simple emit that one and use form tag in webpage.

Comment: yes i am using master page. Other control event working fine like <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"  class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  placeholder="Type here ..." ></asp:TextBox> working fine at the same place

Comment: please try it once simple place your form tag in each web page and emit your form tag in master page. May be it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same code is **working fine** in my PC....

Edited,

try this

add following code inside your Update panel

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlshort" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlshort" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"  />
</Triggers>
```

hope this work....

Comment: other control working fine too 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"  class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  placeholder="Type here ..." ></asp:TextBox>
but dropdownlist not working ...

Answer (score 0):

try the following:
1. add a `try-catch` block and see if you are getting any exception.
2. if your update panel `UpdateMode` is `conditional`, then you have to manually call `Update()` method or the panel will not update.

Comment: main issue is post back not happen